# Response.Cookies["value"].value and Request.Cookies["value"].value inquiry

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0, cookies

I have some question regarding cookies value.
I have this string "R&y1K2jwl:m;%nS0#pvd", I passed it to cookie using Response.Cookies
HttpContext.Current.Response.Cookies["_SecurityCode"].Value = @"R&y1K2jwl:m;%nS0#pvd";

but when I'm trying to read the value of my cookie using this, 
HttpContext.Current.Request.Cookies["_SecurityCode"].Value, I only get "R&y1K2jwl:m" as a value.

Can you help me how to get the whole string using cookies??

Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per my unserstanding %,; etc are not allowed in cookies therefore the text is truncated as shown in below post.
http://www.daaq.net/old/javascript/index.php?page=writing+js+cookies&parent=js+cookies

In ASP.Net you can use System.Web.HttpUtility to safely encode the cookie as below.

```
// Encode
HttpUtility.UrlEncode(cookieData);

// Decode
HttpUtility.UrlDecode(encodedCookieData);
```